# Hide pipe | in Gravity Forms Entry Output

Tags: wordpress, hook, customization, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I need help removing or hiding a  value from the entry displayed on all my Gravity forms[image: Settings for the form]

[image: Form Output]

I want to remove the "|330" from the output... Having only the "1GB" left

Comment: Where are you outputting this (i.e. notification, confirmation, API)? And how (i.e. merge tag, PHP)?

Comment: API... I need to send this data to an external WebHook, found out that the reason why it was failing was because of the "|330"

Comment: How is the data being sent to the webhook? Are you using the Gravity Forms Webhooks Add-On, a hook such as gform_after_submission, or another method?

Comment: Yes, I used the Gravity Forms Webhook Add-On but it was not submitting - It keeps adding the task in queue. I used zapier, and even automate.io to automate the task but unfortunately it wasn't going too. O my for me to find that the error is because I have the "|330" attached to the value which was supposed to be submitted

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [gform_webhooks_request_data](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_webhooks_request_data) filter in the theme functions.php file or a custom functions plugin to modify the data before the Gravity Forms Webhooks Add-On sends it to the designated endpoint.

This example would apply to form ID 1.

```
add_filter( 'gform_webhooks_request_data_1', function ( $request_data ) {
    gf_webhooks()->log_debug( 'gform_webhooks_request_data: before => ' . print_r( $request_data, true ) );
    if ( ! empty( $request_data['4'] ) ) {
        list( $value, $price ) = explode( '|', $request_data['4'] );
        $request_data['4'] = $value;
        gf_webhooks()->log_debug( 'gform_webhooks_request_data: after => ' . print_r( $request_data, true ) );
    }

    return $request_data;
} );
```

Comment: Thanks so much richard... How do I change the form ID and hope this will work for any field?

Comment: Change the 1 on the end of the filter name to match your form ID e.g. `gform_webhooks_request_data_1` could be chaned to `gform_webhooks_request_data_20` if your form ID is 20. The approach used in this example would work with most choice based pricing fields.

Comment: I have tried the above snippet provided by Richard, it didn't work... Or perhaps, is the values going to be different if called using the GF Rest API?

Comment: If you put the code snippet in the theme functions.php file try moving it to a custom functions plugin.

Comment: I used Code Snippet Plugin to inject the code to my website

Comment: The gform_webhooks_request_data filter only applies to feeds being processed by the Gravity Forms Webhooks Add-On, it will not modify entry data which you can retrieve via the REST API. I've updated the example with logging statments which will write to the add-on log when logging of all messages is enabled for the add-on: https://docs.gravityforms.com/logging-and-debugging/

Comment: Kindly check this; https://ibb.co/QNDM3JH

The pipe symbol has been removed, how do i remove the price too.

Comment: Based on that log the feed request body is set to "select fields"  so you don't need the code, instead select the "Add Custom Value" choice in the field mapping drop down and then in the text input which appears enter the field merge tag with the value modifier e.g. `{label:4:value}`

Comment: Thanks so much... This worked out. Thanks so much. I'm really grateful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219105/discussion-between-michael-and-richardw8k).